# Notepad++ - delete all lines with certain text

Tags: notepad++

I have notepad++ 5.8.2 and I was trying to remove all lines starting with 'Processed XXXXX total records' where XXXXX is a various number.
I tried to CTRL+H and put 'Processed.$ in Find what selecting Regular Expression and putting blank in Replace with but it doesn't even find those lines Processed. Did I do something wrong in regex expression to find and replace them?

Comment: Try Processed.*$ instead of Processed.$

Comment: @Luigino, If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, tks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you:

1. Press  <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd>
2. Select `Regular Expression` at the bottom
3. Find <kbd>^Processed \d+ total records.*?</kbd>
4. Click  <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

After, you may want to clean all the blank lines:

1. Find <kbd>^\s*</kbd>
2. Click  <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: '^Processed \d+ total records.*?' worked for me. not sure why '?' is causing problem!

Answer (score 3):

```
^Processed \d+ total records.*$
```

search and replace with blank.

Comment: can you try this `^Processed.*`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what eol designation you use this will delete the line, and leave no blank line.

```
^Processed\d+ total records.*$\n or
^Processed\d+ total records.*$\r\n
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind,... found it right now...
Had just to do .Processed.*$ with Regular Expression and it replaced with blank line then removed blank lines with TextFX integrated plugin

Comment: Notepad++ has that feature without a plugin, it's under Edit->Line Operation->Remove Empty Lines

Comment: Jamby, not in version 5.8.2 at least...I have only Duplicate current lines, Split lines, Join lines, Move Up Current Line and Move Down Current Line...